# Why can't the compiler find the overloaded version of my function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Without `Get` being overloaded (using only the first definition of `Get`) this otherwise compiles ok:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TxALNameValuePair = record
    Name: ansistring;
    Value: ansistring;
    constructor Create(const AName, AValue: ansistring);
  end;
  TxALNameValueArray = TArray<TxALNameValuePair>;

  TxALHTTPClient = class(TObject)
    private
    protected
    public
      Function  Get(const aUrl:AnsiString;
                    const ARequestHeaderValues: TxALNameValueArray = nil): AnsiString; overload;  
      Function  Get(const aUrl:AnsiString;
                    const aRequestFields: TStrings;
                    const aEncodeRequestFields: Boolean=True;
                    const ARequestHeaderValues: TArray<TxALNameValuePair> = nil): AnsiString; overload;      
  end;

constructor TxALNameValuePair.Create(const AName, AValue: ansiString);
begin
  Name := AName;
  Value := AValue;
end;       

function TxALHTTPClient.Get(const aUrl: AnsiString;
  const ARequestHeaderValues: TxALNameValueArray): AnsiString;
begin    
end;

Function  TxALHTTPClient.Get(const aUrl:AnsiString;
              const aRequestFields: TStrings;
              Const aEncodeRequestFields: Boolean=True;
              const ARequestHeaderValues: TArray<TxALNameValuePair> = nil): AnsiString;
begin
end;

var
  aHttpCLient: TxALHTTPClient;
begin
  aHttpClient := TxALHTTPClient.Create;
  aHttpCLient.get('http://www.toto.com', [TxALNameValuePair.Create('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')]);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

But when `Get` is overloaded it produces

> [dcc64 Error] E2250 There is no overloaded
>   version of 'Get' that can be called with these arguments

Why is the compiler not able to resolve this overload?

Comment: @J... no their is no overload directive, also changing TALNameValueArray = TArray<TALNameValuePair> by TALNameValueArray = array of TALNameValuePair work :(

Comment: The Delphi version is important because I suspect that you have a version which supports dynamic array constants.

Comment: @J... You may be right. But then `aHttpClient.get('http://www.toto.com', nil, [TNameValuePair.Create('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')]);` should compile (note the additional `nil` parameter and the `TNameValuePair` type -- no `AL`). It should compile, but it would probably not work.

Comment: @J... Indeed. Without MCVE we can't know, but I suspect, as you said, that aHttpClient is declared as THttpClient, and because Get is not virtual, THttpCliet.Get() is assumed, and then the parameters are wrong. But as you said, without MCVE we don't know. Actually loki is not known for providing an MCVE even when several people asked.

Comment: I just add a complete exemple in the question ...

Comment: @j... for the MCVE I copy the code in the question, yu just need to copy past in delphi. i m in delphi tokyo release 2

Comment: Much better.  I've updated your example to something that is more easily copied and tested.

Comment: thanks @J...  yes your version is much more better ! happy you also see the problem that look more like a delphi bug :(

Comment: I have no problem with the posted console application. Compiles fine in my Tokyo.

Comment: @Victoria did you try the overloaded version ?

Comment: Erm. No. I've tried what I supposed to be MVCE.

Comment: @Victoria That was my edit - I didn't want to duplicate so much code so the MCVE is a working example.  Adding the overload makes it fail.  Maybe it's not clear enough... I'll update.

Comment: I don't see how this q merits the downvotes.

Comment: @MartynA I suspect most (or even all) of the downvotes were incurred before the MCVE was added. Some might _eventually_ get removed now that the question has been edited.

Comment: @MartynA Agreed. Actually, there were two downvotes before the edits. Then it became 4 as far as I can see. I don't have access to history though, so I'm just going by what I saw.

Comment: @JerryDodge Everyone has access to [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49055159/timeline); though not really a complete audit trail. You should have enough rep to see the up/down vote summaries. Unfortunately, the summaries are daily and not per revision. (Unless ofc that's what you were referring to?)

Comment: @Craig Hmm, I never realized that was an option actually. Either way, this is a good question.

Comment: @JerryDodge I agree it's a good question; but only from revision 4. (I first saw it at revision 6.) The sample code in rev 1-3 didn't even use **overload**; and that would have been certain to attract downvotes. The unfortunate thing about a bad first version is that previous downvoters will take a while (if ever) to come back and change their votes. (_Note revision 5 was an improvement, but (as per comments) it turns out there was some confusion about how to use the MCVE correctly._) I see the voting has already swung favourably; so no major cause for concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the dynamic array constructor you are using is producing an object of type `array of TxALNameValuePair`, but all of your overloads require the type to be `TxALNameValueArray`, and it seems that the compiler is not making the connection between `array of TxALNameValuePair` ==> `TArray<T>` for `T => TAxTxALNameValuePair`.

The array can be implicitly converted to the correct type when there is no ambiguity introduced from an overload but otherwise it seems you have to provide that type information somehow. The easiest (and probably clearest) way is just to use a variable.

```
var
  aHttpCLient: TxALHTTPClient;
  nvpArray : TxALNameValueArray;
begin
  aHttpClient := TxALHTTPClient.Create;
  nvpArray := [TxALNameValuePair.Create('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')];
  aHttpCLient.get('http://www.toto.com', nvpArray);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

You can also construct the array in place using a typed dynamic array constructor :

```
var
  aHttpCLient: TxALHTTPClient;
begin
  aHttpClient := TxALHTTPClient.Create;
  aHttpCLient.get('http://www.toto.com', 
                  TxALNameValueArray.Create(
                    TxALNameValuePair.Create('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
                  ));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Otherwise, unless there's a special need for your own name-value pair record type you can just use the one that is supplied in `System.Net.URLClient` :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Classes, System.Net.URLClient;

type
  TxALHTTPClient = class(TObject)
    private
    protected
    public
      Function  Get(const aUrl:AnsiString;
                    const ARequestHeaderValues: TNameValueArray = nil): AnsiString; overload;
      Function  Get(const aUrl:AnsiString;
                    const aRequestFields: TStrings;
                    const aEncodeRequestFields: Boolean=True;
                    const ARequestHeaderValues: TNameValueArray = nil): AnsiString; overload;
  end;

function TxALHTTPClient.Get(const aUrl: AnsiString;
  const ARequestHeaderValues: TNameValueArray): AnsiString;
begin
end;

Function  TxALHTTPClient.Get(const aUrl:AnsiString;
              const aRequestFields: TStrings;
              Const aEncodeRequestFields: Boolean=True;
              const ARequestHeaderValues: TNameValueArray = nil): AnsiString;
begin
end;

var
  aHttpCLient: TxALHTTPClient;
begin
  aHttpClient := TxALHTTPClient.Create;
  aHttpCLient.get('http://www.toto.com', [TNameValuePair.Create('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')]);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

I'm guessing that this works simply because of compiler magic, being a system defined type.

Further down this route, you can equally use `TNetHeaders` instead of `TNameValueArray`, the former simply being an alias of this type.  You can also create your own alias like

```
TxALNameValueArray = TNetHeaders;
```

if you really want.

---

Digging deeper, we can produce a minimal example showing the problem :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TDblArray = TArray<double>;

procedure A(i : integer; da : TDblArray); overload;
begin
end;

procedure A(s : string; da : TDblArray); overload;
begin
end;

begin
  A(1, [1.0]);
end.
```

This does not compile with the same error.

This does work, however:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TDblArray = array of double;

procedure A(i : integer; da : TDblArray); overload;
begin
end;

procedure A(s : string; da : TDblArray); overload;
begin
end;

begin
  A(1, [1.0]);
end.
```

As does this :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses Types;

procedure A(i : integer; da : TDoubleDynArray); overload;
begin
end;

procedure A(s : string; da : TDoubleDynArray); overload;
begin
end;

begin
  A(1, [1.0]);
end.
```

Maybe we want to call this a compiler bug?  I'm not sure.  Normal type resolution works forwards but with overload resolution it has to work backwards... this might be a halting problem situation in the general case.  Could submit a QP if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: but why in this way it's work with delphi THttpClient ? it's same implementation but it's work ...

Comment: @loki `THttpClient` does not overload `Get`.

Comment: function `Post(const AURL: string; const ASourceFile: string; const AResponseContent: TStream = nil; const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil): IHTTPResponse; overload;`   function `Post(const AURL: string; const ASource: TStrings; const AResponseContent: TStream = nil;
      const AEncoding: TEncoding = nil; const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil): IHTTPResponse; overload;`  
function `Post(const AURL: string; const ASource: TStream; const AResponseContent: TStream = nil;
      const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil): IHTTPResponse; overload;`

Comment: function `Post(const AURL: string; const ASource: TMultipartFormData; const AResponseContent: TStream = nil;
      const AHeaders: TNetHeaders = nil): IHTTPResponse; overload;`

Comment: @loki  I see what you mean.  `TNetHeaders` is a system defined type - probably just compiler magic.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: i was curious to know what exactly is this compiler "magic" ... Also replacing TArray<TxALNameValuePair>;
by Array of TxALNameValuePair make everything working ...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. An untyped open array parameter. No such thing. Open array is on the callee side. It can be passed an array or an open array constructor. But here the parameter is declared as a dynamic array. So no open arrays at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : very sorry i not not understand, what doesn't male sense ?

Comment: @loki Compiler magic meaning that the type resolution for `TNetHeaders` --> `TArray<TNameValuePair>` is probably built into the compiler somehow - something that does not work for a custom type.  If you CTRL+Click `TNetHeaders`, for example, the IDE takes you directly to `TArray<T>`.  This is not the case for a custom `TArray<T>` type.

Comment: "The problem here is that you are passing an untyped array argument" is a meaningless statement because you cannot pass an open array. You can only receive an open array. And you aren't. You are receiving a dynamic array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry - sloppy wording.  It's an untyped dynamic array argument.  The point is that the type isn't being resolved.  By "passing", I mean that the caller is providing as argument to the function an array with no type rather than a variable whose type information the compiler can determine at compile time.  I'm not sure how else you want me to word that, but by all means I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Details matter. Open array and dynamic array are very different. And the type could readily be inferred. What is being passed must be a dynamic array. And this must be a dynamic array literal. The type of the single element is clear so why can't the compiler infer it. Smells like a compiler bug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've clarified.